# Do multiplication in excel

Tags: excel, python-2.7, xlrd, xlsxwriter

- I have thanks to xlsx writer completed a workbook with different sheets wit some information about numerical tests I did.
- In a cell, I have written the first parameter I need
- In the adjacent cell, the second one
  What I need to do is to multiply these two cells, and do that for all the rows.

I guess that I cannot use the .write_number(row, col, value) method because I need to read in the excel sheet the values of the two cells I just talked about and multiply them to get "value".
So, at this point I don't know what to do...
Should I close my workbook I am writing in, use xlrd module, read the value of the 2 columns I want to multiply, stock the result in a list, and then re-open and use xlsx writer again ?
Or is there a faster method than that ?

I hope I made myself clear. I started Python one week ago, so please be indulgent.

Regards,

Marco

Answer (score 2):

> In the adjacent cell, the second one What I need to do is to multiply these two cells, and do that for all the rows.

One way would be to use a formula and let Excel do the calculation for you:

```
worksheet.write('C1', '=A1*B1')
```

> I guess that I cannot use the .write_number(row, col, value) method because I need to read in the excel sheet the values of the two cells I just talked about and multiply them to get "value".

If you just wrote the two numbers to the worksheet then presumably you have the data stored or available somewhere in your program. So you shouldn't have to re-read the data out of the Excel file.

Comment: and admitting that I want to apply the formula on the length of the table in my excel sheet? Do I have to write a loop with for i in range(sheet.nrows): ... or is there something close to worksheet.write('C', '=A*B') ?